Does a debt exist for a Parking Charge Notice?
A question on Personal Finance & Money asks for options to pay a parking "fine" when the recipient is not trusted.  The asker is not arguing that they owe the money but, for security reasons, they do not want to use any of the methods offered by the parking company to make the payment.  The comment below on one of the answers raised a good question.

This is a fine i.e. there is an obligation to pay: surely this implies that the Legal Tender rules are relevant and they are obliged to accept cash?

My understanding is, that legal tender must be accepted when a debt exists.  Even though, in strict terms, the charge is being made by a private company and, again to my understanding, is not a fine, does this create a debt that cannot legally be refused to be settled with cash?

In practice legal tender will be meaningless in almost all situations since to exercise the right you have to pay the money into court and the court service now only accepts payment by cheque/postal order etc and not in cash unless you are unable to obtain them, eg if you are homeless and can't get a bank account.

@FrancisDavey You may be surprised to learn how many people are homeless and cannot get a bank account.  Furthermore, many homeless people live in vehicles and are subject to regular parking "fines" as there is often no legal place to park their shelter.

@EndAntisemiticHate -that's interesting. I had assumed that the number of people who have no access to a bank/building society etc account and the those with cars was minimal, but I am happy to admit I was wrong if that is the case.

england-and-wales
A parking penalty charge or penalty charge notice or parking charge notice creates a civil debt.
The person has accepted they owe some money to the car park management - the person is in debt to the management.

Legal tender is Royal Mint coins (with some limits) and Bank of England notes.
Cheques, debit card payments, credit card payments, contactless payments, electronic transfers etc are not legal tender.
If you're in debt to a creditor, you offer to pay a debt in 'legal tender' and your offer is refused, your creditor can't then sue you for not paying off the debt.
Legal tender doesn't mean a shop is obliged to sell you something just because you want to pay in cash.

You tagged this E&W.  There are no legal tender banknotes in Scotland or Northern Ireland (as your link says) though there are several different banknote issuers.

As to the last sentence, is the difference there that the shop only gets to refuse before they've sold you something, not after (at which point you do have a debt with them)? I.e. agreeing to the transaction inherently binds you to needing to accept legal tender to complete it?

@Flater  How can a shop refuse AFTER they have sold you something? If you take the goods out of the shop without paying, then surely that becomes theft (in most cases) even if you have offered to pay?

@MikeB cafes/restaurants/service offerers are probably more relevant to the "pay after" question (where giving back the product/service isn't possible)

Yes but isn't it true that a genuinely disputed debt cannot be pursued… which in effect means the issuing of the notice doesn't in itself create an actionable debt?

@Flater; MikeB In normal retail shopping legal tender doesn't apply, because no debt exists.
Any contract requires one party to provide goods or services in return for 'a consideration' from the other, and that includes retail shopping.
Most contracts specify when the consideration must be paid. Most obviously, rent may be due annually, quarterly, monthly, weekly, daily or whenever…
Retail shopping 'contracts' rely not written detail but ancient custom, insisting goods and considerations be exchanged simultaneously. No debt exists, so legal tender can't apply.
More…

…further The situation is wholly different if the retailer accepts a deposit.
Then, a debt does exist whether the goods are handed over then and there, or not.
Either way, the goods become the property of the buyer when the deposit is paid, which means if they're stored in a back room, the retailer has a duty to preserve them for some while, which is one reason why some stores won't accept deposits…

@RobbieGoodwin: The assumption with retail is that you can synchronize the transfer of goods (i.e. ownership over it) to when the payment takes place, thus meaning that a debt is instantaneously resolved as it is created. But this isn't always fully the case, e.g. when something is custom built or irreparably adjusted based on customer specifications, before the customer has paid for it. If the store is willing to take the item back, then it reverts what I first mentioned (ownership synchronized to payment), but if the store refuses to take ownership again, must they then accept legal tender?

@RobbieGoodwin Just for pedantry's sake, the assumption here is that there was no explicit agreement as to the payment method. Assume I called a shop, put in an order for a customized mug to be paid for on pickup, but we never explicitly discuss payment method. I show up with cash. The store owner refuses to accept cash, and refuses to nullify the transaction because he already customized the mug. Can I be forced to pay using different methods?

@Flater No. You can not be forced to pay using 'different methods' unless refusal to accept cash was explained by the store and acknowledged by you at the time the contract was made.
In your case 'we never explicitly discuss payment method' means any contract will fall under what the Court considers to be standard custom and practice, dragging you right back to coda…

@RobbieGoodwin: That's the point I was initially making. The agreement to the sale can be a different point in time from the actual transfer of money, hence being able to be in a debt situation that (without prior agreement) must allow for legal tender to be used to resolve it.

@Flater If you're not talking about normal retail sales, you've lost any interest of mine.
If you're still talking about normal retail sales, no: the agreement to the sale cannot occupy a different point in time.
All I'm trying to tell you is that in normal retail sales the contract must be executed at the exact moment it is made, when ownership of goods and monies in payment therefor, are simultaneously transferred.
Hence by definition, no debt ever being possible and therre being nothing else to it.
Why not ask your own or any other lawyer?

To answer the headline question: no
See Collection agency trying to collect on parking ticket? (Is this advice accurate?)
Only the government can issue fines and thereby create an enforceable debt. Private parties cannot just assert that a debt exists by calling it a fine; there has to be a legal basis for the creation of the liability - a contract or a tort, for example.
Even if you agree that you owe the debt, you and the creditor have to agree (in the contract or subsequently) how it will be paid. If you can’t agree, then you don’t have to do anything. The creditor is unlikely to be happy with this state of affairs, so they may choose to sue for recovery. The debtor can then contest the suit or accept the judgment debt. There will then be an enforceable debt (which will now include the additional costs of going to court), which can be paid into the court in legal tender.
You misunderstand what legal tender means

Legal tender has a very narrow and technical meaning in the settlement of debts. It means that a debtor cannot successfully be sued for non-payment if they pay into court in legal tender. It does not mean that any ordinary transaction has to take place in legal tender or only within the amount denominated by the legislation.

The debtor does not have to accept cash. However, once there is a judgment debt, the creditor can pay the court in cash, who will then pay the debtor using a sensible payment mechanism.

This answer (first complete sentence) seems to deny the existence of private debt, but (some forms of) currency itself contains the words "legal tender for all debts, public and private".  The second half of the answer is more sensible and relevant, although it ignores that many jurisdictions have laws requiring acceptance of cash.

@BenVoigt A debt is only legally a debt (and subject to legal tender rules) when it has been the subject of a judgment—until then, it's just a private arrangement. Also, the UK has no such law about cash.

A private debt is an enforceable debt. There is a means to legally enforce it. This is true whether or not the creditor has a right to insist upon payment by a means other than legal tender.

Truly, only the (various levels of) government can issue fines but how does that help, here? That says nothing about various service providers creating enforceable debts.
Along with transport operators such as bus and rail companies, parking service providers do clearly have rights to issue various charges, creating enforceable debts.
Whether such charges are correctly applied in any given case is a different question.

How you could imagine a debt to be legal only when subject to judgement? Don't you think judgement confirms or denies something already existing?
Do you not think more likely, the debt is legal except when struck out by judgement?
The ability to enforce the debt is subject to judgement and how could your 'private arrangement…' not be a contract?
'The UK has no such law about cash' means strikes me as wholly unclear. Will you rephrase it, please?

@RobbieGoodwin a disputed debt is not a debt until the dispute is resolved. You saying I owe you money does not a debt make.

Sorry, Dale. That's not how it works.
A debt is a debt, until the Court says otherwise. You pretending I owe you money does not an argument make.
If the validity of the debt is challenged, the truth is up to the Court to decide but that is not what you said.
It is clear that a disputed debt cannot be enforced but again, that's not what you said.
Why not ask your own or any other lawyer?

@RobbieGoodwin a debt is a debt. An assertion of a debt is just a noise.

Yes, Dale. Exactly that is what I've been trying to tell you. I'm sorry my efforts were so clumsy and thankful you now see it!

@RobbieGoodwin I think you’re missing my point in the answer. The OP says he has received a private fine. There is no such thing. Therefore he is not indebted to the parking company, at least, not on that basis.
